# Convert coordinates in a region into a numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a rectangular region, where the lower left (min) and upper right (max) coordinates. I want to make a Numpy array that consists of coordinates in the region. For example, the min and max are (3, 8) and  max (0, 6), respectively. The numpy array I want to make is

[image]

Additionally, I have a requirement that the grid in the region may be smaller than 1. For example, 0.5 makes X = [[3.0, 0] [3.5, 0] [4.0, 0] [4.5, 0] ...]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [use `numpy.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html):

```
>>> numpy.mgrid[3:8, 0:6].T
array([[[3, 0],
        [4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0],
        [7, 0]],

       [[3, 1],
        [4, 1],
        [5, 1],
        [6, 1],
        [7, 1]],

        ...

       [[3, 5],
        [4, 5],
        [5, 5],
        [6, 5],
        [7, 5]]])
```

If you want a "flat" array of tuples, you can reshape it:

```
>>> numpy.mgrid[3:8, 0:6].T.reshape((-1, 2))
array([[3, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [7, 0],
       [3, 1],
       ...
       [6, 5],
       [7, 5]])
```

Comment: Wow, it is wonderful. Is there a way to set a step size to be smaller than 1?

Comment: @YoungsupKim Yes. `numpy.mgrid[0.0:1.0:0.1, 3.5:4.5:0.2].T.reshape((-1, 2))`.